# OCR detection in iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, ocr

Can OCR detection be done in iphone? If so can anyone provide me links which help me in developing OCR recognition in iphone?

Thanks 
Rakesh

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062755/ocroptical-character-recoginition-libraries-for-iphone/9064231

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try working out TesserAct api.its working very well. i have Send you a demo Application Link Below.

Sample Code Of the OCR .
http://github.com/nolanbrown/Tesseract-iPhone-Demo

Thanks

Parag

Answer (score 3):

The Nolan Brown project which parag mentioned uses an earlier version of tesseract(I guess 2.04) and also incorporating it in your project is not easy as it might seem.

My advise is to use [3.0 version](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/list) of tesseract and it also requires the [leptonica](http://www.leptonica.com/) library. [Here](http://tinsuke.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-compile-and-use-tesseract-3-01-on-ios-sdk-5/) is a very good tutorial on how to include these on ios sdk 5 .... you can also look at the [release notes](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/ReleaseNotes) of tesseract for added features in different versions ...

I personally implemented this but the results are not that great to be honest.. :/

Comment: The link you have for the tutorial is broken :(

Comment: The site is up, but the direct link you've put in to the tutorial at http://tinsuke.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-compile-and-use-tesseract-3-01-on-ios-sdk-5/ doesn't work, gives 404